# How to autogenerate such instances with Generic usage?

Tags: haskell, generics

I have:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}

module FlexibleId where

import Data.Char
import Data.List.Split
import Control.Applicative (Alternative((<|>)))
import GHC.Generics ((:+:), Generic)

newtype Name = Name String deriving newtype (Eq, Ord, Show)
newtype PK = PK Integer deriving newtype (Eq, Ord, Show)
newtype XXX = XXX String deriving newtype (Eq, Ord, Show)

class FlexibleId a where
    typeSuffix :: String
    readId :: String -> Maybe a

instance FlexibleId Name where
    typeSuffix = "name"
    readId s | all isAccepted s = Just $ Name s where isAccepted c = isAlphaNum c || c == '_'
    readId _ = Nothing

instance FlexibleId PK where
    typeSuffix = "pk"
    readId s | all isDigit s = Just $ PK $ read s
    readId _ = Nothing

instance FlexibleId XXX where
    typeSuffix = "xxx"
    readId s | all isDigit s = Just $ XXX s
    readId _ = Nothing

-- order matters!!!
data FlexibleUserId = UserPK PK | UserName Name | UserXXX XXX deriving (Show, Generic)
instance FlexibleId FlexibleUserId where
    typeSuffix = "User-key"
    readId s =
        case splitOn ":" s of
            [s1, "pk"] -> UserPK <$> readId s1
            [s1, "name"] -> UserName <$> readId s1
            [s1, "xxx"] -> UserXXX <$> readId s1
            [s1] -> (UserPK <$> readId s1) <|> (UserName <$> readId s1) <|> (UserXXX <$> readId s1)
            _ -> Nothing
```

And I want to be able to derive automatically `FlexibleId` instances for the types like `FlexibleUserId` (like manually written `instance FlexibleId FlexibleUserId` here) - *in short, it parses some ID which can be a key (digits) or something else, all variants are different constructors of the `FlexibleUserId` parameterized with `Name`, `PK`, `XXX`; also parser is able to use a hint like "xyz:name"*. Is it possible to achieve this with `Generic` instances? Could you show me, how it looks, I have not idea how to use all these `:+:`, `K1`, `U1`, etc. magic.

EDIT: my try

I started with this, but I have not idea how to get constructors of `a` and `b` so to return not just `id1` but `SomeConstructor1 <$> id1` instead of:

```
instance (FlexibleId (a p), FlexibleId (b p)) => FlexibleId ((a :+: b) p) where
    typeSuffix = "xxx"
    readId s = undefined
        where
            suf1 = typeSuffix @(a p)
            suf2 = typeSuffix @(b p)
            id1 = readId @(a p) s
            id2 = readId @(a p) s
            z = case splitOn ":" s of
                    [s1, suf1] -> id1
                    [s1, suf2] -> id2
                    _ -> Nothing
```

Also I don't know how to get rid of `p` after it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a definition of a generic function `greadId` such that you can write that instance as:

```hs
instance FlexibleId FlexibleUserId where
    typeSuffix = "User-key"
    readId = greadId "User"
```

`greadId` takes as its first argument the common prefix `"User"` to strip out of the constructor names, and the input string. It tries to split the input string, and defers to another function `greadId_` for further parsing:

```hs
greadId :: (Generic a, GFlexibleId (Rep a)) => String -> String -> Maybe a
greadId prefix s =
  case splitOn ":" s of
    [s1, suffix] -> to <$> greadId_ prefix s1 (Just suffix)
    [s1] -> to <$> greadId_ prefix s1 Nothing
    _ -> Nothing
```

`greadId_` is part of a class, to implement the generic machinery:

```hs
class GFlexibleId f where
  greadId_ ::
    String {- type prefix to strip ("User") -} ->
    String {- input string (before ":") -} ->
    Maybe String {- optional input suffix (after ":") -} ->
    Maybe (f p)
```

In order, we have instances for:

- `D1`: type metadata (where we have access to the type name `"FlexibleUserId"`, which we ignore here)
- `(:+:)`: sums
- `C1`: constructor metadata (the constructor name `"UserPK"`)
- `S1`: field metadata (the field name (none here), strictness annotations; also ignored here)
- `K1`: field contents (where we call `FlexibleId`)

```hs
instance GFlexibleId f => GFlexibleId (D1 c f) where
  greadId_ pre s suf = M1 <$> greadId_ pre s suf

instance (GFlexibleId f, GFlexibleId g) => GFlexibleId (f :+: g) where
  greadId_ pre s suf = (L1 <$> greadId_ pre s suf) <|> (R1 <$> greadId_ pre s suf)

instance (GFlexibleId f, Constructor c) => GFlexibleId (C1 c f) where
  greadId_ pre s suf | isMatch = M1 <$> greadId_ pre s suf
                     | otherwise = Nothing
    where
      isMatch = case (suf, stripPrefix pre cname) of
        (Just z, Just z') -> z == map toLower z'
        (Nothing, _) -> True
        (_, _) -> False
      cname = conName @c undefined  -- conName doesn't use its argument

instance (GFlexibleId f) => GFlexibleId (S1 c f) where
  greadId_ pre s suf = M1 <$> greadId_ pre s suf

instance FlexibleId a => GFlexibleId (K1 i a) where
  greadId_ _ s _ = K1 <$> readId s
```

Test:

```
ghci> readId "333:pk" :: Maybe FlexibleUserId
Just (UserPk 333)
```

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/21594fe5918ad77c5605edd71fc0dd1d

Comment: should be `ghci> readId ...` not `ghci> greadId ...`. Thank you very much!